# ¿como puedo asignar coordenadas en con un array pdf?

Tags: pdf, fpdf

buenas estoy generando un pdf, la pregunta es, cuando imprimo los datos al usar un foreach, al momento que da la segunda vuelta como le puedo asignar las nuevas coordenadas y asi para las q siguen por ejemplo si son 50 registros, asignarles las coordenadas.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $pdf->Text(6,45,$data[0]->fecha_registro);


if (strlen($data[$key]->nombre) > 28)
{
        $pdf->Sety(25);
        $pdf->setx(44);     
        $pdf->MultiCell(41, 20,trim($data[$key]->nombre));
        $pdf->Ln();
}else{
        $pdf->Text(25, 45,$data[$key]->nombre);
    }

if (strlen($data[$key]->tipo) > 28)
{
        $pdf->Sety(44);
        $pdf->setx(127);        
        $pdf->MultiCell(41, 20,trim($data[$key]->tipo));
        $pdf->Ln();
}else{
        $pdf->Text(127, 44,$data[$key]->tipo);
    }
```

Tengo eso y en mi objeto  tengo registrado 20 personas, de ahi ya no se como hacerle para que cuando vuelva el foreach y cambia $key a 1 darle las coordenadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando pasa por primera vez me llena los datos (color azul)asi como en la imagen, despues al dar la segunda vuelta quiero q me llene el siguiente(rojo), y por logica cuando recorra al rojo cambian las coordenadas si las dejo asi como en la primera se encima todo, mi documento pdf es una plantilla la tabla esta echa ya predefinida desde word.

Comment: podrias poner tu codigo para tener una idea mas clara de lo que deseas lograr y lo que has tratado de realizar...!!

Comment: @Tegito123 Listo